# How can I use column reference in REGEXP_REPLACE in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, oracle12c

My script looks like this :

```
SELECT
    regexp_replace(column1,'"resId":([^"]+?)..','"resId":column2,"')
FROM
    table;
```

Here, I need to replace resId value in column1 by value from column2.

Comment: You may want to include your table definition, some sample data, and expected results. As it stands now your question isn't particularly clear.

Comment: Probably use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` on your column2 extract the needed value and  then use it inside `regexp_replace`.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell without the sample data and expected output what you exactly want.

It appears you are expecting to transform a pattern like this - **`"resId":Value1,"otherid":othervalue`**

Please note I took into consideration that a key value pair of 
`"resID":value` exists in the data and there is a separator ( a space or a comma) between such key-value pairs.

`(,|$)` indicates a comma separator or end of line after the `value`. You may change this to contain any separator in your data that **distinguishes** it from other combinations. If there is no such thing and the data is purer than this, you should care to *describe it clearly* by editing your question, which may help us to provide you a proper solution.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1244e/5)

**Query**:

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       regexp_replace(column1,'"resId":[^"]+(,|$)','"resId":' || column2 || '\1') as replaced
FROM t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1244e/5/0)**:

```
|                             COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |                            REPLACED |
|-------------------------------------|---------|-------------------------------------|
| "resId":Value1,"otherid":othervalue |  Value2 | "resId":Value2,"otherid":othervalue |
| "otherid":othervalue,"resId":Value1 |  Value2 | "otherid":othervalue,"resId":Value2 |
```

Answer (score 1):

Concatenate the `column2` value into your replacement string:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(
         column1,
         '"resId":([^"]+?),"','"resId":' || column2 || ',"'
       )
FROM   table;
```

However, if you data is well-formed JSON and the `"resId"` value will be a simple literal (not an array or an object) then you can use a regular expression that would parse this like:

```
'("resId":)(null|true|false|(-?0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d*)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?|"(\\["\/bfrnt]|\\u\d{4}|[^"\/'||CHR(8)||CHR(9)|| CHR(10)||CHR(12)||CHR(13)||'])*")'
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c182/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name ( column1, column2 ) AS
  SELECT '{"resId":null}', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"resId":true}', 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"resId":false}', 3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"resId":123}', 4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"resId":""}', 5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"resId":"\r\n"}', 6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"resId":"test"}', 7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"resId":"' || CHR(13) || CHR(10) || '"}', 8 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT column1,
       column2,
       regexp_replace(
         column1,
         '("resId":)(null|true|false|(-?0|[1-9]\d*)(\.\d*)?([eE][+-]?\d+)?|"(\\["\/bfrnt]|\\u\d{4}|[^"\/'||CHR(8)||CHR(9)|| CHR(10)||CHR(12)||CHR(13)||'])*")',
         '\1' || column2
       ) As repl
FROM   table_name
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c182/2/0)**:

```
|          COLUMN1 | COLUMN2 |           REPL |
|------------------|---------|----------------|
|   {"resId":null} |       1 |    {"resId":1} |
|   {"resId":true} |       2 |    {"resId":2} |
|  {"resId":false} |       3 |    {"resId":3} |
|    {"resId":123} |       4 |    {"resId":4} |
|     {"resId":""} |       5 |    {"resId":5} |
| {"resId":"\r\n"} |       6 |    {"resId":6} |
| {"resId":"test"} |       7 |    {"resId":7} |
|       {"resId":" |       8 |     {"resId":" | -- Note: not well-formed JSON 
|               "} |         |             "} | -- so did not get matched.
```